# Tkinter - Create table using database fetched data

Tags: python, tkinter, supabase

I'm learning Python and I want to make a GUI using Tkinter module. I'm reading some articles about usage and now I'm trying to create a simple table that needs to be pupulated from data fetched from a supabase indatnce. I've writed this code but when I try to debug it the application will crash. How I need to fix it to get a table that will show the desired informations? How I add a label for each column?

```py
supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)
#
response = supabase.table('pdvList').select('*').execute()

# Creting application window 
window = Tk()
window.title("Test screen")
window.geometry("300x300")

# Creating table
for r in range(len(response.data)):
    for c in range(15):
        e = Entry(window, width=20, fg='blue', font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
        e.grid(row=r, column=c)
        e.insert(END, response.data)


#window.resizable(False, False)
#
frame = ttk.Frame(window, padding=10)
#
frame.grid(row=r, column=c)
#
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use [ttk.Treeview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview) for showing table like data.

Comment: Any example please?I'm new to pyton so didn't know the correct implementation for the Treeview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to show data in form of a table is by using a `Treeview` widget from `tkinter`. Setting up a `Treeview` with `tkinter` is quite straightforward. I don't know how the data inside `response` will be accessible, so I am using a mock data here. The example is dynamic, so if you follow the same structure but have different columns OR data, the treeview will also adapt like so:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

response = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Afghanistan"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Albania"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Algeria"},
]
cols = list(response[0].keys())

root = Tk()

# Create a treeview with columns from `response`
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=cols, show="headings")
tree.pack()

# Add columns to treeview
for col in cols:
    tree.heading(col, text=col)
    tree.column(col, width=100, anchor="center")

for res in response:
    # Insert each item into the treeview
    tree.insert("", "end", values=list(res.values()))

root.mainloop()
```

Your code might have to change slightly based on how you retrieve the data from `response`.

[Read more about `ttk.Treeview`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The data are contained inside a property of the response object from supabase that is named `data`. So I wll have `response.data` that will contain the informarions I want to display inside the table. I will try the code you've suggested and read about `Treeview` to better understand how to use it.